# Unmet dependencies in Mysql server and Myserver Client when I tried to install "Lamp server"

Tags: server, mysql, 18.10, lamp

**This is Ubuntu 18.10.** I'm a BCA student. And Linux is one of my subjects. I want to install Lamp server,

```
pranav@rasingan:~$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgssapi3-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhttp-message-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libnghttp2-14' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libencode-locale-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwind0-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libsasl2-modules-db' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libldap-2.4-2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libevent-core-2.1-6' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libbrotli1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libheimntlm0-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-fast-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhttp-date-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl-modules-5.26' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblwp-mediatypes-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libfcgi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libheimbase1-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-pm-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaio1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-json' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-opcache' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libsasl2-2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libio-html-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libperl5.26' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-tagset-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libsasl2-modules' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libldap-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.2-readline' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhcrypto4-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblua5.2-0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libsodium23' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libtimedate-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libroken18-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libasn1-8-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libkrb5-26-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libgdbm-compat4' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-utils' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhx509-5-heimdal' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-parser-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php7.2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liburi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.34-1ubuntu2).
apache2-bin is already the newest version (2.4.34-1ubuntu2).
apache2-bin set to manually installed.
apache2-data is already the newest version (2.4.34-1ubuntu2).
apache2-data set to manually installed.
apache2-utils is already the newest version (2.4.34-1ubuntu2).
apache2-utils set to manually installed.
libaio1 is already the newest version (0.3.111-1).
libaio1 set to manually installed.
libapr1 is already the newest version (1.6.3-3).
libapr1 set to manually installed.
libaprutil1 is already the newest version (1.6.1-3).
libaprutil1 set to manually installed.
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version (1.6.1-3).
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 set to manually installed.
libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version (1.6.1-3).
libaprutil1-ldap set to manually installed.
libasn1-8-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libasn1-8-heimdal set to manually installed.
libbrotli1 is already the newest version (1.0.6-1).
libbrotli1 set to manually installed.
libcgi-fast-perl is already the newest version (1:2.13-1).
libcgi-fast-perl set to manually installed.
libcgi-pm-perl is already the newest version (4.40-1).
libcgi-pm-perl set to manually installed.
libencode-locale-perl is already the newest version (1.05-1).
libencode-locale-perl set to manually installed.
libfcgi-perl is already the newest version (0.78-2build1).
libfcgi-perl set to manually installed.
libgdbm-compat4 is already the newest version (1.14.1-6).
libgdbm-compat4 set to manually installed.
libgssapi3-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libgssapi3-heimdal set to manually installed.
libhcrypto4-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libhcrypto4-heimdal set to manually installed.
libheimbase1-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libheimbase1-heimdal set to manually installed.
libheimntlm0-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libheimntlm0-heimdal set to manually installed.
libhtml-parser-perl is already the newest version (3.72-3build1).
libhtml-parser-perl set to manually installed.
libhtml-tagset-perl is already the newest version (3.20-3).
libhtml-tagset-perl set to manually installed.
libhttp-date-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libhttp-date-perl set to manually installed.
libhttp-message-perl is already the newest version (6.18-1).
libhttp-message-perl set to manually installed.
libhx509-5-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libhx509-5-heimdal set to manually installed.
libio-html-perl is already the newest version (1.001-1).
libio-html-perl set to manually installed.
libkrb5-26-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libkrb5-26-heimdal set to manually installed.
liblua5.2-0 is already the newest version (5.2.4-1.1build1).
liblua5.2-0 set to manually installed.
liblwp-mediatypes-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
liblwp-mediatypes-perl set to manually installed.
libnghttp2-14 is already the newest version (1.32.1-1build1).
libnghttp2-14 set to manually installed.
libroken18-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libroken18-heimdal set to manually installed.
libsasl2-2 is already the newest version (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2).
libsasl2-2 set to manually installed.
libsasl2-modules is already the newest version (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2).
libsasl2-modules set to manually installed.
libsasl2-modules-db is already the newest version (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2).
libsasl2-modules-db set to manually installed.
libsodium23 is already the newest version (1.0.16-2build1).
libsodium23 set to manually installed.
libtimedate-perl is already the newest version (2.3000-2).
libtimedate-perl set to manually installed.
liburi-perl is already the newest version (1.74-1).
liburi-perl set to manually installed.
libwind0-heimdal is already the newest version (7.5.0+dfsg-2).
libwind0-heimdal set to manually installed.
libwrap0 is already the newest version (7.6.q-27).
libwrap0 set to manually installed.
ssl-cert is already the newest version (1.0.39).
ssl-cert set to manually installed.
libldap-2.4-2 is already the newest version (2.4.46+dfsg-5ubuntu1.1).
libldap-2.4-2 set to manually installed.
libldap-common is already the newest version (2.4.46+dfsg-5ubuntu1.1).
libldap-common set to manually installed.
libperl5.26 is already the newest version (5.26.2-7ubuntu0.1).
libperl5.26 set to manually installed.
perl is already the newest version (5.26.2-7ubuntu0.1).
perl set to manually installed.
perl-modules-5.26 is already the newest version (5.26.2-7ubuntu0.1).
perl-modules-5.26 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-5.7 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note, that i already have "Mysql" installed like a month ago:

```
pranav@rasingan:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

And i also have installed Lamp like a month ago:
[image: screenshot]

You might be thinking when everything is fine, why i am reinstalling it?
Well, i am following a tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ossbZhcOMI4&feature=youtu.be). And the terminal should have shown me, "Lamp server is already installed". Did i did something wrong installing LAMP before? How can i update Lamp server if there a new available one along with its all other components?

> Some output people requested that might help this case:

```
pranav@rasingan:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for pranav: 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:11 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Fetched 252 kB in 3s (78.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
pranav@rasingan:~$ apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
  Version table:
     5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.23-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Note that, below commands doesn't resolve this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Comment: How did you install mysql before ? Did you install the **latest version**, or from LAMP stack?

Comment: It was like 5 months ago @Emmet I don't remember. But i did installed latest version 8.0.15. Do u want me to reinstall from the beginning by purging everything?

Comment: Please run `dpkg -l | grep mysql`

Comment: @Emmet i did ran, what am i looking here? Does u want me to include that output in the question?

Comment: You have broken dependencies. Just try fix it with `sudo apt-get install -f` - I you want to update the installed lampp, the `upgrade` procedure is enough : `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - And, just an idea : first read the official documentation, and if you can not read, you can go watch youtube and then ask youtube for help

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade don't do nothing. @cmak.fr I did that before asking this. so.

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get update` ? Please always edit/paste the output of your tries... And the output of this `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7`

Comment: @cmak.fr (I run "update" command every time i boot the device.) Anyway, the question is updated.

Comment: @karel I tried that too.

Comment: Try correcting the broken packages automatically in Synaptic.

Comment: @karel Are u telling me to select "Fix Broken Packages" and then "Reload" from Synaptic? I did that too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your repository is fetching mysql 5.x version and you have already installed mysql community server 8.x version . So your console is trying to install mysql 5.x version side by side !

In order to install it you have to remove mysql 8.x version completely than retry

Comment: this means i can't installed Xamp because it uses old "mysql" version, right? @Manas